# assert equal for numpy object

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, unit-testing

I have 2 npz files I'd like to compare through an assert from numpy testing module:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.testing.html

From documentation I understood that `.npz` files are loaded as `instance` :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html
https://www.kite.com/python/docs/numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile

From my understanding I thought `.npz` files were dict but they are loaded as `instance` and I end up with this error :

```
AssertionError: 
Items are not equal:
 ACTUAL: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x11d96c690>
 DESIRED: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x11d97a5d0>
```

here is my code :

```
import numpy as np

_npz_test = np.load(npz_test, allow_pickle=True)
_npz_res = np.load(npz_res, allow_pickle=True)
np.testing.assert_equal(_npz_test, _npz_res)
```

Those `.npz` files are composed of 3 different `files` to which I can access when printing:

```
_npz_test.files
```

I suppose I could use a workaround by iterating through the `keys` but I'd like a one line solution to do this.

I can share the files if needed

Comment: Assert equal expects array-like objects, opened npz files are not arrays. You can either iterate over the keys, or open the files as byte arrays and compare them.

Comment: is there any way to make it as something on which I could apply an assert ?

Comment: `[np.testing.assert_equal(_npz_test[x],_npz_res[x])  for x in _npz_test.keys()]` will throw assert error if they are not equal, also you need to verify that all the keys exists in both objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `assert_equal` is able to handle `numpy` objects inside simple Python containers like `dict` and `list`, it's not flexible enough to handle more generic containers. And the object returned by `load` is not actually a dictionary or a subclass of a dictionary. It's just a "[dictionary-like object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load)," so `assert_equal` doesn't know what to do with it.

Fortunately this is quite easy to handle. We can explicitly convert the objects to dictionaries:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = numpy.array([4, 5, 6])
>>> numpy.savez_compressed('foo.npz', a=a, b=b)
>>> numpy.savez_compressed('bar.npz', a=a, b=b)
>>> foo = numpy.load('foo.npz')
>>> bar = numpy.load('bar.npz')
>>> numpy.testing.assert_equal(dict(foo), dict(bar))
```

I'm not sure this will work work for all corner cases, but it's likely to work most of the time.

Comment: I didn't thought of doing it this way !
But it's funny it's not working when transforming it to a dict using dict(), but it's working when transforming it to a list using list(), at least for me...
So I propose you to edit your post and replace dict with list. Thank you !

Comment: @DPrat, could you say more then about how the `.npz` files are saved? It doesn't really make sense to me that `list` would work while `dict` would not. I want to make sure I understand what's going on so that the answer is as correct as possible.

Comment: @DPrat after looking at a couple of things, I'm concerned that using `list` is producing incorrect results. If you call `list` on a dict-like object, you get a sequence of keys — just the keys. So I'm concerned that it's not checking for equality of arrays, it's just checking that the two objects have the same keys.

Comment: indeed you were right, using list was returning a list of keys. I had to workaround this by iterating over the keys of the numpy object and converting each to a dict